# Truly long spaghetti

Tags: pasta, spaghetti

Something I recall from my childhood, but which I last recall seeing about 45 years ago, is long boxes (about 2 feet long, 5" x 5" in square cross section) of spaghetti pasta with very long noodles inside, each bent in the middle making each piece of uncooked pasta about 4 feet long.  Two of the brands I recall (of which I may be in error) were Salerno and Aligheri.  Recently I have been searching the web to try to find this, but cannot even find a reference.  Does anyone remember this, and does anyone know if this is still available?  If I recall correctly, the boxes also had the infamous "pasta number" on them, either "5" or "8", depending on the box.

Comment: Something like http://www.amazon.com/Cecco-Filippo-Spaghetti-Lunghi-Archetto/dp/B0012KPXHW ? 'Each noodle is 4ft long'

Comment: OR, you could make them yourself. Making noodles of any kind is not rocket science.

Comment: My husband talks about the same box of spaghetti that sat next to the stove as a kid. Has anyone been able to find this long spaghetti?

Comment: If you're in for the ultimate in pasta longness: Your chinese grocer might have some tolerably spaghetti like noodles in 1lb packages that just say "chinese noodle" (sic!) or similar. This is not a typo in translation.

Answer (score 11):

I imagine you are thinking of [spaghetti curvati](http://www.pastaigragnanesi.it/pastaigragnanesi/en/products/product-details.html?id=80) (o *spaghetti con curva*, that is, spaghetti with a bend).

It is a pasta format typical of Southern Italy.

Some brands refer to those as [spaghetti lunghi](http://www.pastagarofalo.it/us/products/range/specialty-cuts/) (long spaghetti).

I am not aware of a specific name for them, although I am fairly sure there are names in various Italian dialects.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this pasta locally here, so I know it's available. I will check on brand names next time I see it and update this post.

Specifically I have seen it in artisan shops that import speciality ingredients from Italy as well as farmers markets and Italian grocery stores and markets. I would start with seeing if you have any Italian markets where you are.